# PHP session related issue

Tags: php, session

Is session  necessary for user login checking or it can be done alternatively by checking the username with database matching?? If it is done by database checking with the username or email then what is necessecity of Session? please tell me with explanation if possible..thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session is a type of cookie that used for tracking user after login! for example: after user submitted username and password, and you did matched against database, then, you probably don't want to authenticate again (re checking username and password for every page hit), therefore, you can save an identifier in session for recognizing user that successfully logged-in.

Usually, seesion will be expired once user closed the windows, while, cookie can be kept for long time.

Basic Logic:

1. Check if username and password submitted
2. Check if submitted username and password exists in the database
3. If second condition true, then create session

Comment: Can u plz tell me where is the reauthentication? I mean I didnt get "for every page hit"

Answer (score 0):

No, session is not necessary for user checking.Session is for keeping track of a user as he moves on your website.As the user navigates your pages session keeps track of him.For example,a user on this site,has all its data "with him" no matter what page he`s on.

Comment: I have done  a form in index.php on which by submitting it goes to members.php page where I am checking the username with database with the help of mysqli_num_rows. If it is equal to 0 then the user login is not successful. Is it ok?

Comment: Dont worry about details,if you are a beginner.Post if you have a specific problem,and code, code, code.

Comment: thats the problem. I have tried many times to post the code but it is not taking..I am new to this website...I dont know exactly the way to post the code.